# XML RPC issue with PHP and JS

Tags: php, javascript, xml-rpc

I have to send the following XML RPC request and I have tried in many ways, though I am not able to do it.

Do you have any idea how could I send this through PHP or JavaScript ?

> boolean cache.purge ( int apiUserId, string authString, string currentDate, string url )

Please let me know if you need more info.

Here is the request I must send: http://wiki.netdna.com/Glossary/API_Documentation#cache.purge
Here is a PHP example: http://wiki.netdna.com/Glossary/API_Documentation#PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on http://wiki.netdna.com/Glossary/API_Documentation#PHP.
The following line is used :

```
$f=new xmlrpcmsg("$namespace.$method", array(php_xmlrpc_encode($apiUserId),
```

But :

```
$namespace = 'cache';
$method = 'purge';
```

So the "cache.purge" message will be sent.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do. I want to purge a file from the cache. Really I don't understand anything from the XML-RPC. I've never worked with it. Here's the response I get http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NNuXaQYH